# CSS show specific Clip of Image (Overlapping with Parent) for further Filters

Tags: css

Please take a look at my attached picture.
What I want to achieve is, that the Rectangle you see (lets think of it as a div), has a background-image (chess-pattern) just like the parent (entire image). The thing is, the child (Black Rect), should only draw the part of the background-image, where it is overlapping with the parent (To process further effects e.g. blur).

So i fought if there would be a css trick to:

- Only draw the clip of an image where it is overlapping with the parent (also could be the entire body)  or
- Have a dynamically CSS functionality to get its own position and calc the image-position it has to show. ( e.g. something like `background-position: [Position-X-Of-Div] 100px;`)

I'm glad for any help! Please feel free to ask, if something is not clear.

If that is not possible, I'm also willing to switch to sass, less

[image]

Comment: *If that is not possible, I'm also willing to switch to sass, less* - Both compile to CSS so what's impossible in CSS is impossile in them too.

Comment: Did not knew that. At the moment I have problems computing positions an thought that less / sass are more dynamic here

Comment: CSS preprocessors know nothing of your HTML so they can't do anything "dynamic" for the said *HTML* (in particular, a coordinates a browser will render anything at).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a pseudo element, you could do something like this

Unfortunately CSS does not have a built-in function to calculate a value from both itself and its parent in the way needed in this case, so you'll need a script to adjust the `inner::before` left/top value relative to the `inner` left/top, so the former is a negative of the latter.

```js
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.inner');
    el.classList.add('moveme');
  });
})();
```

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 95vh;
  height: 95vh;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcSoj.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10vh; 
  top: 10vh;
  width: 40vh; 
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10vh; 
  top: -10vh;
  width: 95vh;
  height: 95vh;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcSoj.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.inner.moveme {
  animation: moveme 3s linear forwards;
}
.inner.moveme::before {
  animation: moveme2 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes moveme {
  from { transform: translate(0,0); }  
  to   { transform: translate(20vh,20vh); }  
}
@keyframes moveme2 {
  from { transform: translate(0,0); }  
  to   { transform: translate(-20vh,-20vh); }  
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for divs which do not change their position.
I also can use background-attachment:fixed; to not have to compute positions! The Problem which exists is, that background-attachment:fixed; does not work when being animated (slide effect) and I have troubles to compute the positions otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelRampl Use pseudo, and when you animate, animate left/top values on both the element and its pseudo

Comment: @MichaelRampl Updated my answer with an animation